# Limit amount of categories displayed in a post

Tags: posts, categories

I'm trying to limit the amount of categories that show up above my post title, below is an example of what is happening [image]
I'm fine with just grabbing the first 2 categories that show up and limit them to that.

I have found functions that accomplish this with tags but nothing with categories. For example in this custom function, it limits the tags to five in `functions.php`

```
add_filter('term_links-post_tag','limit_to_five_tags');
function limit_to_five_tags($terms) {
return array_slice($terms,0,5,true);
}
```

Then in `single.php` use `<?php the_tags() ?>`.

Any idea how to accomplish this with categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your functions.php, you can filter `the_category_list`, which is an array of categories for a post.

```
function wpse_the_category_list( $categories, $post_id ) {
  return array_slice( $categories, 0, 2, true );
}
add_filter( 'the_category_list', 'wpse_the_category_list', 10, 2 );
```

And then display the categories in your template file with:

```
the_category();
```